# Hide/Show TextBox Items Dependant On Export Format

Tags: reporting-services

I need hide a text box when export to excel format. I'm using SRSS 2008, not (SRSS 2008 R2),

I Locate the Hidden property of the text box to hide, and write the following expression:

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", True, False).
```

But in this version of Reporting Services not appear *"RenderFormat.Name"* option, somebody knows other way to do this in SRSS 2008?.

Answer (score 2):

The global variables that expose rendering formats were a [new feature of SSRS 2008 R2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/02/globals-renderformat-aka-renderer-dependent-report-layout.aspx).  Prior to R2 there wasn't / isn't a way for the report to know what format was selected by the user to export.

I think your only option (other than upgrading to R2) is to create two versions of the report.  One that is intended for export to EXCEL and one that isn't.